# How to schedule a repeating task to count down a number in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I need to just have a simple task that runs as long as the user is on one specific screen. On this screen there is a count down timer.

I looked into Background Agents - but that seems not to be the right approach.

Basically it should work like this: The user goes to this one screen, presses start and the cont down timer starts to count down - every 30 seconds update is perfectly ok.

How should I do this on WP8 ?

Comment: You're asking how to make a countdown timer in C# or I'm I missing the point?

Comment: Thanks - I am actually not sure what alternatives I have on WP8. That's why I am asking - on Android and iPhone I scedule a repeating task, where I can define what it does. I need to do more than just show a count down number every 30 seconds - while the app is running and while the user may work with the app, push buttons, etc. The perdiodic update should just be a task that is repeated every 30 secs

Comment: If you are looking into doing stuff in the background while the app is NOT in the foreground you have to use Background Agents which can only run every 30min as the shortest interval.

Comment: no, the app is in the foreground..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a DispatcherTimer as wkempf points out. Pretty simple to create actually. Something like this (where you have a TextBlock named countText in your xaml:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;
    private int _countdown;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _countdown = 100;
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) => Tick();
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Tick()
    {
        _countdown--;

        if (_countdown == 0)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }

        countText.Text = _countdown.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Dispatcher.BeginInvoke should not be needed in the Tick method. The DispatcherTimer should raise the Tick event on the thread associated with the Dispatcher already.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous Timers in .NET. System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer is probably what you want, but System.Threading.Timer might be what you want as well. Depend on whether you want to run the periodic code in the background or on the UI thread.