# Dispatchtimer sample needed

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

Windows phone app dispatch timer.

I am looking for a good example of how I can use a timer to update my phone data every second.
So far I have info on using DispatchTimer, but haven't yet been successful in producing a re

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500) };
        timer.Tick += TimerTick;
        timer.Start();


       private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var timer = sender as DispatcherTimer;
           if (timer != null)
           {
                // Write your code here .......
                timer.Tick -= TimerTick;

           }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a [look at my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874981/how-to-schedule-a-repeating-task-to-count-down-a-number-in-windows-phone-8/13882717#13882717) which includes an example of using a dispatchertimer to enable a countdown on a screen.