# automatic redirection after specific time in WP8

Tags: windows-phone

I'm developing windows phone 8 application.
I have two pages ; one of the page is the start up one ; Once the user open the application this page will appear and automatically after a specific time ; it will redirect the user to the main menu of the application .

How I can make an automatic redirection after specific time in WP8 ?

Answer (score 2):

May be these lines of code helps you:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private DispatcherTimer timer;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {  
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        //Set your specific time here using TimeSpan instance
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        timer.Tick += (s, e) => {
            var frame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            frame.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        };
        timer.Start();
    }    
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874981/how-to-schedule-a-repeating-task-to-count-down-a-number-in-windows-phone-8) for the a timer implementation. Only thing left to do is, when the timer finished, call a navigation method to navigate to the main menu.